# Why am I getting the error "undefined method `expect'" when running a system test on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

When I run my system test using `rails test:system` I receive the following error:

```rb
Error:
PaymentSessionsTest#test_payment_succesful_if_valid_details_provided:
NoMethodError: undefined method `expect' for #<PaymentSessionsTest:0x00007fffd82485d0>
Did you mean?  exec
    test/system/payment_sessions_test.rb:26:in `block in <class:PaymentSessionsTest>'
```

#### Background

I am writing my first system test for rails and I have a page that takes a while to load. From the [Capybara documentation](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#navigating) it recommends using the `expect` method eg. `expect(page).to have_current_path(payment_success_url)` which will use Capybara's waiting behaviour (so the test doesn't time out before the page has loaded). However, when I do this I receive the error above.

I'm a little confused as to whether `expect` is part of Capybara or RSpec. It's in Capybara's documentation so I assume it should *just work* but I'm currently stuck.

#### Relevant source code

```rb
# test\system\payment_sessions_test.rb

require "application_system_test_case"

class PaymentSessionsTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
  setup do
    @event = events(:one)
  end

  test "payment successful if valid details provided" do
    # Enter payment details on invite page
    visit event_url(@event)
    fill_in "Your name", with: "John Doe"
    fill_in "Email", with: "test@test.com"
    fill_in "Gift amount", with: "20"
    click_on "Pay"

    # Stripe Checkout
    fill_in "cardNumber", with: "4242424242424242"
    fill_in "cardExpiry", with: "01#{Date.today.next_year.strftime("%y")}" # grab year always as next year in 2 digit format
    fill_in "cardCvc", with: "123"
    fill_in "Name on card", with: "Mr John Doe"
    fill_in "billingPostalCode", with: "N1 7GU"
    click_on "Pay"

    # Payment success page
    expect(page).to have_current_path(payment_success_url) # ensure Capybara waits for page to load after clicking Pay
    assert_selector "h1", text: "Payment successful!"
  end

end
```

```rb
# test\application_system_test_case.rb

require "test_helper"

class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  driven_by :selenium, using: :chrome, screen_size: [1400, 900]
  # driven_by :selenium, using: :headless_chrome

  def setup
    # ensure url helpers use correct host and port for system tests
    Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = Capybara.current_session.server.host
    Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:port] = Capybara.current_session.server.port
  end

end
```

```rb
# test\test_helper.rb

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative '../config/environment'
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'bcrypt' # required for devise (used when creating encrypted password for user fixtures)
require 'pry'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include HashidsHelper

  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers # include devise test helpers in all tests

  setup do
    # set hashid for each event record
    # NB. can't set using fixtures as event.id is dynamic
    FixMissingHashidsService.run
  end
end
```

```rb
# Gemfile

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  # gem 'chromedriver-helper'
  # Using chromedriver in Windows, added to path, via WSL1
end
```

#### Details and versions used

- Rails 5.2.3
- Running via WSL (1) and using Windows chromedriver binary (Chrome opens and tests run - other tests not using `expect` run fine)
- Using Stripe Checkout test gateway within the test (ie. it actually goes to checkout.stripe.com/pay/cs_test_etc...) as part of the test flow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Artur, `expect` is part of RSpec. If you're using minitest then you need to use the mintest assertions provided by Capybara, which you're already doing with `assert_selector`. The one you're missing is `assert_current_path` - https://rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/Capybara/Minitest/Assertions#assert_current_path-instance_method

```
assert_current_path(payment_success_url)
```

Since you're using a 3rd-party service directly in your tests timings are going to be slow and you may need to increase Capybaras waiting time. There are multiple ways to do that

1. Globally
   `Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 20` in one of your setup files
   This has the downside of potentially increasing time until failure in all of your tests
2. For a block of actions. This increases the max wait time for all assertions inside the block (individual max not total)

```
   Capybara.using_wait_time(20) do
     assert_current_path(payment_success_url)
     assert_selector "h1", text: "Payment successful!"
   end
```

3. Most calls accept a wait parameter to change the value just for that call - which probably makes the most sense in this instance

   ```
   assert_current_path(payment_success_url, wait: 20)
   ```

Note: you might want to look into using something like https://github.com/thoughtbot/fake_stripe rather than hitting Stripe directly during most of your tests for performance reasons

Note: you should always prefer one of the Capybara provided assertions over plain `assert` when dealing with anything relating to the browser in your system tests.

Comment: This was really helpful and I appreciate you linking directly to the relevant docs. I now grok that I'm using Minitest over RSpec with Capybara, which would have helped my Googling earlier :) I ended up using `assert_current_path(payment_success_url, ignore_query: true)` to get it to work as I have dynamic query params. If you could add a mention about potentially increasing `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` as it looks like I'm interacting with a 3rd party, and where exactly this is set (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61410569/3471900) I will happily accept yours).

Comment: @jaredlt Updated and included better solutions than increasing the global max wait time

Comment: Your answer has provided more value than I ever expected to get. I'm humbled by the generosity of strangers on the internet! Thank you and hope you have a great day

Answer (score 0):

`expect` belongs to the `RSpec`. It is indeed in the Capybara docs, but under the RSpec section, that's why you are getting the error message. Try to use assert instead.

Comment: I assume you mean to use `assert current_path == payment_success_url`? This doesn't work because it needs to wait for the page to load. I want to take advantage of Capybara's waiting behaviour by using `have_current_path`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by doing the following:

- Remove the `expect` line from the test (this is indeed part of RSpec and not Capybara - thanks [@artur.prado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61407034/3471900))
- Add `Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 20` to `application_system_test_case.rb` (I set 20 because the Stripe Checkout test gateway is very slow. The beauty of Capybara being that it doesn't wait the whole 20 seconds, just 'up to' 20 seconds - it will run as soon as it is able). There may be other implications to doing this, given Capybara sets the default at 2 seconds. Given this test is interacting with a 3rd party domain I am ok with it, but buyer beware.

```rb
# test\application_system_test_case.rb

require "test_helper"

class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  driven_by :selenium, using: :chrome, screen_size: [1400, 900]
  # driven_by :selenium, using: :headless_chrome

  Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 20 # Stripe Checkout test gateway is slooooow

  def setup
    # ensure url helpers use correct host and port for system tests
    Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = Capybara.current_session.server.host
    Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:port] = Capybara.current_session.server.port
  end

end
```

EDIT: Instead of setting max wait time globally, see better option in [Thomas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61410541/3471900).

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, defining `matcher` outside `rspec` should solve the problem. Adding the next two lines on top of this file will enable you to use `expect` method outside the context of `RSpec`

```
require "application_system_test_case"
require "minitest/autorun"                             # new line
require "rspec/expectations/minitest_integration"      # new line
class PaymentSessionsTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
 setup do
   @event = events(:one)
 end

 test "payment successful if valid details provided" do
   # Enter payment details on invite page
   visit event_url(@event)
   fill_in "Your name", with: "John Doe"
   fill_in "Email", with: "test@test.com"
   fill_in "Gift amount", with: "20"
   click_on "Pay"

   # Stripe Checkout
   fill_in "cardNumber", with: "4242424242424242"
   fill_in "cardExpiry", with: "01#{Date.today.next_year.strftime("%y")}" # 
   grab year always as next year in 2 digit format
   fill_in "cardCvc", with: "123"
   fill_in "Name on card", with: "Mr John Doe"
   fill_in "billingPostalCode", with: "N1 7GU"
   click_on "Pay"

   # Payment success page
   expect(page).to have_current_path(payment_success_url) # ensure Capybara 
   waits for page to load after clicking Pay
   assert_selector "h1", text: "Payment successful!"
 end

end
```